# "TypeError: node.getIterator is not a function" in SCSS compilation after migration to Angular 11 (custom webpack)

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, tailwind-css, postcss-loader

An error occures in the loading of scss-files in my Angular project. This error appeared first after I migrated from Angular v9 to v11 (I followed the migration guide and all went smooth).

### The error:

```
Error: ./src/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: node.getIterator is not a function
```

This error is shown for each .scss file, that fails to parse.

### The context:

The project is making use of the `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` webpack builder. I use this because we are making use of **Tailwind CSS**.

Webpack has a config for postCSS:

```js
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    postcssOptions: {
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                        plugins: ['postcss-import', 'tailwindcss', 'autoprefixer'],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

The `angular.json` file is pretty standard.

### The dependencies:

- Angular: ^11
- @angular-builders/custom-webpack: ^11
- postcss: ^8.2.6
- postcss-import: ^14.0.0
- postcss-loader: ^4.2.0
- postcss-scss: ^2.1.1
- node: v15.8.0 - *(I was wondering if this could be an issue, because I got some warnings on packages. However, I downgraded node with nvm and the same error occurred after reinstalling  the packages and running it again.)*

Any pointers to see where it could go wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research there were two things that really helped:

- I started **using the default @angular-devkit packages in angular.json**. That means that the whole added complexity of webpack could be removed. A good guide is: https://dev.to/angular/setup-tailwindcss-in-angular-the-easy-way-1i5l.
  (This might be the solution for you if this error occurs).
- Reading the tailwindCSS docs... https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrading-to-v2 showed that **some classes were renamed** and some other classes got new values.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and I solved it by reading the doc of postcss-loader:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-loader#extract-css

I had to change webpack.config.js into the following. You might want to adapt to your case. Let me know if it worked !

```
const isProductionMode = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";


module.exports = {
  mode: isProductionMode ? "production" : "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          isProductionMode ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader :
            "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: {
                    postcssOptions: {
                        ident: "postcss",
                        syntax: "postcss-scss",
                        plugins: [
                            require("postcss-import"),
                            require("tailwindcss"),
                            require("autoprefixer"),
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: isProductionMode ? "[name].[contenthash].css" : "[name].css",
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: This fixed most of the problems. The basic styles (for all the classes in HTML) are added. However, the custom styles are not working (inside a .scss file for a component for example). The imports doesn't seem to work for the other style-files in the project.

Comment: using `require("postcss-import")` fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. In my case, I had copied my configuration from another project and forgot to install postcss-scss as a dev dependency.  Instead of giving an error about a missing node module, postcss just silently failed and complained about node.getIterator

While researching the problem, I read from the authors of postcss that you will only see this error if the AST tree created by postcss is broken somehow by a plugin.  One way this happens is if your old postcss plugins are designed for postcss 7 instead of the latest postcss 8. Another way the AST tree can break is if a plugin is undefined entirely, which is what happened in my case when I forgot to install postcss-scss